# In nestjs is it possible to inject a specific provider only for routes in a controller, and use a default provider for other controllers

Tags: nestjs

I have a `APP_INTERCEPTOR` implementation `ResponseInterceptor` which depends on a `ResponseService` provider. For a particular controller a `UserResponseService` extended from `ResponseService` needed to be used.

I used DI token like this

global.module

```
{
    provide: ResponseService,
    useClass: ResponseService
}
```

users.module

```
{
      provide: ResponseService,
      useClass: UsersResponseService,
}
```

But this is using the `UserResponseService` everywhere which was not my intention. What can I do to use `UserResponseService` only for `users.controller` and `ResponseService` everywhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by making a request-scoped factory function to determine which service to use depending on the request path:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'ResponseService',
    inject: [REQUEST, ResponseService, UsersResponseService],
    useFactory: (request: Request, responseService: ResponseService, usersResponseService: UsersResponseService) => ResponseServiceFactory(request, responseService, usersResponseService)
  }
  ...
]

export function ResponseServiceFactory(request: Request, responseService: ResponseService, usersResponseService: UsersResponseService) {
  if (
    [
      // all the paths for which you need to use this service.
    ].includes(request.originalUrl)
  ) {
    return usersResponseService;
  } else {
    return responseService;
  }
}
```